# How to get start and end of day in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get start ( 00:00:00 ) and end ( 23:59:59 ) of today in timestamp ( GMT )? Computer use a local time.

Comment: To get local time use `var end = new Date; end.setHours(23,59,59,999); console.log(end);` Approved answer gives you wrong timestamp

Answer (score 822, accepted):

```js
var start = new Date();
start.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);

var end = new Date();
end.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999);

alert( start.toUTCString() + ':' + end.toUTCString() );
```

If you need to get the UTC time from those, you can use `UTC()`.

Comment: I would recommend that `var end = new Date(start.getTime());` to ensure that you have same point in time - in the event you change dates between start and end initialisation - it can happen - just a good habit to get into

Comment: @MartynDavis when all is normal operation, usually about 0-2 ticks happen in between but it depends on how busy the cpu is so then it makes sense to do that if you are worried about 1 tick precision.

Comment: I would also recommend using `setUTCHours` instead of `setHours` to get Universal time

Comment: Things might have changed but for me this sets the start to UTC start for the previous day, and to UTC end for the previous day.

Comment: Please read @sidonaldson's extremely important comment. Using `setHours` is dangerous as it sets the local hours, instead of UTC hours.

Comment: In 2020, you can instead use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` to handle timezones. I have posted an answer below showing how it works. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 263):

With [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) library, use [`startOf`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/start-of) and [`endOf`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/end-of) methods as follows:

**Local GMT:**

```
const start = dayjs().startOf('day'); // set to 12:00 am today
const end = dayjs().endOf('day'); // set to 23:59 pm today
```

[For UTC:](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/utc)

```
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');
dayjs.extend(utc);

const start = dayjs.utc().startOf('day'); 
const end = dayjs.utc().endOf('day');
```

---

Using the (deprecated) [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library, this can be achieved with the [`startOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`endOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) methods on the moment's current date object, passing the string `'day'` as arguments:

**Local GMT:**

```
var start = moment().startOf('day'); // set to 12:00 am today
var end = moment().endOf('day'); // set to 23:59 pm today
```

[**For UTC:**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

```
var start = moment.utc().startOf('day'); 
var end = moment.utc().endOf('day');
```

Comment: And we should use `.toDate()` in the end to get the date.

`var end = moment().endOf('day').toDate();`

Comment: add `.unix()` at the end to get unix timestamp in seconds :) like this: `moment().startOf('day').unix()`

Comment: moment js somehow doesn't work if I have a predefined Date object e.g. `moment(new Date()).endOf("day");`doesn't work, but `moment().endOf("day");` does work.

Comment: What about the start of day for a specified time zone?

Comment: how to get the start and end of a selection day? such as 01/01/2018?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn To get the start of day for a specified timezone, you can use `moment-timezone` and do this: `moment().tz('America/Chicago').startOf('day').toDate()`.

Comment: Beware no milliseconds are added. When we send this over the wire to a .NET web api, Is there a way where this is mapped to the very last possible date for a given day? So ticks included..?

Comment: MomentJs is now deprecated - might consider providing an option in date.fns

Answer (score 14):

Using the [luxon.js](http://moment.github.io/luxon/) library, same can be achieved using startOf and endOf methods by passing the 'day' as parameter

```
var DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
DateTime.local().startOf('day').toUTC().toISO(); //2017-11-16T18:30:00.000Z
DateTime.local().endOf('day').toUTC().toISO(); //2017-11-17T18:29:59.999Z
DateTime.fromISO(new Date().toISOString()).startOf('day').toUTC().toISO(); //2017-11-16T18:30:00.000Z
```

> remove .toUTC() if you need only the local time

and you may ask why not [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), answer is [here](http://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/why.html) for that.

Comment: The link explaining why not moment.js is broken. The short answer is: Moment Js recently announced that the library is now deprecated. Luxon is beautiful!

Answer (score 14):

FYI (merged version of Tvanfosson)

> it will return actual date => date when you are calling function

```
export const today = {
  iso: {
    start: () => new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString(),
    now: () => new Date().toISOString(),
    end: () => new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)).toISOString()
  },
  local: {
  start: () => new Date(new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toString().split('GMT')[0] + ' UTC').toISOString(),
  now: () => new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0] + ' UTC').toISOString(),
  end: () => new Date(new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)).toString().split('GMT')[0] + ' UTC').toISOString()
  }
}
```

// how to use

```
today.local.now(); //"2018-09-07T01:48:48.000Z" BAKU +04:00
today.iso.now(); // "2018-09-06T21:49:00.304Z" *
```

* it is applicable for Instant time type on Java8 which convert your local time automatically depending on your region.(if you are planning write global app)

Answer (score 14):

**One liner - considering local timezone and without libraries**

```js
const todayStart = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
const todayEnd = new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999))

const tomorrowStart = new Date(new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1))
const tomorrowEnd = new Date(new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1))

const monthStart = new Date(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
const monthEnd = new Date(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0).setHours(23, 59, 59, 999))

const nextMonthStart = new Date(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 1).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
const nextMonthEnd = new Date(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 2, 0).setHours(23, 59, 59, 999))

console.log({
  todayStart,
  todayEnd,
  tomorrowStart,
  tomorrowEnd,
  monthStart,
  monthEnd,
  nextMonthStart,
  nextMonthEnd,
})
```

Answer (score 10):

In [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/) We can declare it like :

```
   const start = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:01');
   const end = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59');
```

Comment: so much more helpful!

Answer (score 9):

As you are interested in the UTC start/end of day, you can also use the modulo operator:

```
const now = new Date().getTime();
let startOfDay = now - (now % 86400000);
let endDate = startOfDay + 86400000;
```

where 86400 is the number of seconds of one day and the resulting variables are the Epoch in milliseconds.

If you prefer `Date` Objects:

```
const now = new Date().getTime();
let startOfDay = new Date(now - (now % 86400000));
let endDate = new Date(now - (now % 86400000) + 86400000);
```

Comment: The end time will be "12am" the following day, I think you want `let endDate = startOfDay + 86400000 - 1` instead to get the last millisecond of the current day.

Answer (score 8):

If you're just interested in timestamps **in GMT** you can also do this, which can be conveniently adapted for different intervals (hour: `1000 * 60 * 60`, 12 hours: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 12`, etc.)

```
const interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hours in milliseconds

let startOfDay = Math.floor(Date.now() / interval) * interval;
let endOfDay = startOfDay + interval - 1; // 23:59:59:9999
```

Comment: **Important caveat:** this only works if you're wanting the time in UTC. (This is what the question asked for... but I feel I should warn anyone who came here from a Google search and didn't realize this.)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) library for date manipulating. It is really great modular and consistent tool. You can get start and end of the day this way:

```js
var startOfDay = dateFns.startOfDay;
var endOfDay = dateFns.endOfDay;

console.log('start of day ==> ', startOfDay(new Date('2015-11-11')));
console.log('end of day ==> ', endOfDay(new Date('2015-11-11')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No support for UTC handling.

Comment: For UTC and zone support you can check https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz

Answer (score 5):

We can use `moment` for this.

```
// for day start time
moment(moment().startOf('day')).format('HH:mm')

// for day end time
moment(moment().endOf('day')).format('HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the most rated answer, but to define the dates in just one line:

```
const startToday = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0));
const endToday = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23,59,59,999));
```

Explanation:

```
new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0) // returns the epoch time number
new Date(/* epoch number */) // returns that epoch Date object
```

that is why both `new Date` constructors are needed.

Comment: This is cleaner, nice.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little tricky, but you can make use of `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.

The snippet bellow can help you convert any date with any timezone to its begining/end time.

```js
const beginingOfDay = (options = {}) => {
  const { date = new Date(), timeZone } = options;
  const parts = Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
    timeZone,
    hourCycle: "h23",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
  }).formatToParts(date);
  const hour = parseInt(parts.find((i) => i.type === "hour").value);
  const minute = parseInt(parts.find((i) => i.type === "minute").value);
  const second = parseInt(parts.find((i) => i.type === "second").value);
  return new Date(
    1000 *
      Math.floor(
        (date - hour * 3600000 - minute * 60000 - second * 1000) / 1000
      )
  );
};

const endOfDay = (...args) =>
  new Date(beginingOfDay(...args).getTime() + 86399999);

const beginingOfYear = () => {};

console.log(beginingOfDay({ timeZone: "GMT" }));
console.log(endOfDay({ timeZone: "GMT" }));
console.log(beginingOfDay({ timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo" }));
console.log(endOfDay({ timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo" }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// get current time for UTC timezone
const d = new Date();
const year = d.getUTCFullYear();
const month = d.getUTCMonth();
const day = d.getUTCDate();
// set time to begin day UTC
const startTime = Date.UTC(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
//set time to end day UTC
const endTime = Date.UTC(year, month, day, 23, 59, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get current time for UTC timezone
const d = new Date();
const year = d.getUTCFullYear();
const month = d.getUTCMonth();
const day = d.getUTCDate();
// set time to begin day UTC
const startTime = Date.UTC(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
//set time to end day UTC
const endTime = Date.UTC(year, month, day, 23, 59, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.