# Determine start and end time of current day (UTC) (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, utc

I am trying to determine start and end time of the current day in UTC.

Currently this is my solution. `

```
var starttime = date.getTime() -(date.getHours() * 3600000 ); //subtracting a hours to go back to start time of the day.
var endtime = low + 86400000; //adding 24 hours to the start time 
   `
```

Any help is appreciated ! Thank you

Comment: Duplication question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636617/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-day-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Thank you everyone. This is what worked for me !! :)

```
 var d = new Date();
 var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
 var month = d.getUTCMonth();
 var day = d.getUTCDate();

 var startHour =Date.UTC(year,month,day,0,0,0,0);
 var endHour = startHour + 86400000;
```