# How Do You Represent Tomorrow Morning?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Using `momentjs`, I am trying to represent tomorrow at 7:00 AM (in server time).

Something like this:

`var tomorrowEarlyAm = moment().add(1, 'day').add(7, 'hour');`

However, of course, adding 1 day means we are at this same time tomorrow, so adding 7 hours is *basically* adding 31 hours.

The difficulty is that I don't know a simple way of clipping this to midnight:

`var tomorrowMidnight = moment().add(1, 'day').??`

Comment: `moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day').add(7, 'hour');`

Comment: you may want to refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636617/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-day-in-javascript/29328933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you can go to today's 12 AM by using `.startOf('day')`  and then add one day `.add(1, 'day')` and then 7 hours `.add(7, 'hour')`
all to gather as bellow,

```
moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day').add(7, 'hour');
```

as suggested by @Mat J

or you may add 31 hours directly

```
moment().startOf('day').add(31, 'hour');
```