# represent the end of the day in moment.js without the time zone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I was expecting the following to return `2020-01-01T23:59:59`
But due to my time zone being GMT+2, it results in this `2020-01-01T21:59:59.`

How do I represent the end of the day as **23:59:59** from a date that is parsed using `moment.js`

```
var date = moment("2020-01-01").endOf("day").toDate();
```

Comment: Are you okay with hackey solutions? because you could set the time to midday, print out the Y-m-d format, and then just add `'T23:59:59'` to the end

Comment: But that won't work if you have other reasons for wanting to do this sort of 'timezone normalizing' your'e talking about

Comment: `var date = moment.utc("2020-01-01").endOf("day").toDate().toISOString();`

Comment: Or, if you want to do it without moment, in the current timezone, `var date = new Date(2020, 0, 2); date = new Date(date.valueOf() - 1);`

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004222/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao try to call `.utc` in `moment` like:

```
var date = moment("2020-01-01").utc().endOf("day").toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the date as a moment object, up until you need to display it. Just simply call `format` on the object.

```js
console.log(moment.utc('2020-01-01').endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```