# Filter array of object based on date range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This problem is quite easy but I still can't handle it.
I have an array of object let's say something like:

```
const array = [{id:1,created_at: 2022-03-14T16:40:10.000000Z}, {id:2, created_at:2022-03-15T16:40:10.000000Z}
```

I want to filter element using moment.js, and having back only the element that have date of creation of today.

What i want to achieved is something like this:

```
const filtered = array.filter((item)=> item.created_at >= startOfToday && item.created_at <= endOfToday
```

Filtered will look like: `[0]{id:2, created_at:2022-03-15T16:40:10.000000Z}`

Thanks in advance for any tips/answers.

Comment: You should ask your backend developer to make day filter.

Comment: And the actual problem/question is? You already mentioned momentjs. Did you check their [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/)?

Comment: are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636617/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-day-in-javascript

Comment: momentjs even has an [`.isBetween()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) method

Comment: Thank you to both, didn't see that method on the documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `statOf` and `endOf` to make your filter work?

```
const filtered = array.filter(item => {
  const createdAt = moment(item.created_at)
  const startOfToday = moment().startOf('day')
  const endOfToday = moment().endOf('day')
  return createdAt.isBetween(startOfToday, endOfToday)
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, returning empty array

Comment: Are the items in your array from today? In your question I see March 14 and 15, but today might be March 16.

Comment: Yes, on my array i have lot of date with 15/03 and one with 16/03, so i expect to have back one element in the filtered array

Comment: https://codepen.io/Levi-D/pen/xxpwLWG

I left you the pen to check it

Comment: I fixed it @LeviD. It didn't work because `endOf` and `startOf` mutate the `Moment`. This is annoying, a bit unpredictable, and really why moment isn't maintained well anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! Yes, seems that moment give back a Moment object where we cannot do any comparation.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Pure Vanilla JavaScript

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "Iron Man", released_on: "2002-08-21T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { name: "Captain Amoos", released_on: "2008-08-21T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { name: "Amoos John Wick", released_on: "2014-08-21T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { name: "James Bond", released_on: "2021-08-21T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { name: "Loin King", released_on: "2022-08-21T00:00:00.000Z" },
];


let fromDate = "2004-01-01";
let toDate = "2020-11-22";

const filteredData = (data, key, startDate, endDate) => {     
     startDate = new Date(startDate).getTime();
     endDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();
  
  return data.filter( d => {
    let time = new Date(d[key]).getTime();
    return ( startDate < time && time < endDate )
  });
}

console.log(
  filteredData(arr, "released_on", fromDate, toDate)
);
```