# Firebase - Realtime databse : How to display only data recorded today?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm on a vuejs and firebase project.
And I would like to display only the data recorded today.
But I don't know how to do it.
Can you please help me.

```
   created() {
    const dfRef = db.ref("Colis Requetes")
      dfRef.orderByChild("created_at").on("value", (dataSnapshot) => {
        const itemsArray = [];
        dataSnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          const childData = childSnapshot.val();
          const childDataKey = childSnapshot.key;
          this.Colis = childData;
          itemsArray.push({
            id: childDataKey,
            client_name: childData.client_name,
            client_phone: childData.client_phone,
            colis_type: childData.colis_type,
            payment_method: childData.payment_method,
          });
        });
        this.Colis = itemsArray.reverse();
      });
   }
```

The `orderByChild` property is for displaying data from the most recent date to the oldest date. However, I want only the recordings made today to appear on the page.

I'm on a vuejs and firebase project.
And I would like to display only the data recorded today.
But I don't know how to do it.
Can you please help me.

Comment: I am just guessing but maybe try `var start = new Date(); start.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);`. Then in the query, add `where("created_at", ">=", start)` after selecting the collection. Something like this.

Comment: Realtime Database, no Cloud firestore

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a [filtering operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) for that, most likely `startAt`.

If your `created_at` contains a timestamp (going forward, please include such information in your question), that'd be something like:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0); // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636674

const dfRef = db.ref("Colis Requetes")
dfRef
  .orderByChild("created_at")
  .startAt(start.getTime()) // 
  .on("value", (dataSnapshot) => {
    ...
```