# Epoch Value: How to set the time 12AM next day?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say I have an epoch value 1665531785000 which converts to "Tuesday, October 11, 2022 11:43:05 PM" in human readable format.

How can we modify 1665531785000 to 1665532800000 which converts to "Wednesday, October 12, 2022 12:00:00 AM"(set the value to 12AM next day) in javascript/typescript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get start and end of day in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636617/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-day-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Doing complex date math is something you probably want to use a library for. There are a handful of options, but for example [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) is a library that could be used for this:

```js
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(1665531785000))
  .plus({ day: 1 })
  .startOf('day')
  .toJSDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of your example, I assume you would like to use UTC.
You can do it without any additional libraries as below.

```
let d = new Date(1665531785000);
d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);
d.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0);
const e = d.valueOf();

console.log(e);
```