# Firestore get all Documents between two dates

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
query(meetingsCollection, where("start", "in", today), orderBy("start", "asc")
```

I'd like a Firestore query, so that I can fetch all documents between 02/12/2022 - 00:00:00.000 && 03/12/2022 00:00:00.000, ordered by the Date property start, so that I can bucketsize my firestore data request and limit overreads, then use said documents to visually filter accordingly via the front-end.

Can you assist me with this?

Comment: Not sure if you were aware of it but the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) covers how to create a query very similar to the code you're asking us to write for you. See the docs Also be sure questions are clear; 'between' would not include the date, so it would be greater than (>) one date and less than (<) the other. If you want to include that date (inclusive) it would be greater than or equal to (>=) and less than or equal to (<=)

Comment: You can't filter > on one field and < on another. Comparisons can only run on one field. Quote: "In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field." - But thanks for your comment...

Comment: Thanks and I am aware of that, lol (7 years working with Firebase). I was referring to the two *dates* not two *fields*

Comment: I am asking for clarity if you wanted to query between two dates inclusive or exclusive to further refine an answer to match the question if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the actual solution =>>

```
const now = new Date();

const getDateFormatted = (date) => {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
} 

const startNow = new Date(`${getDateFormatted(now)}T00:00:00.000z`); //2021-09-01T00:00:00.000Z
const endNow = new Date(`${getDateFormatted(now)}T23:59:59.000z`);

const nowEvents = ref([]);

const getNowEvents = async () => {
  onSnapshot(myEvents(startNow, endNow), (querySnapshot) => {
    let tmpEvents = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let event = {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        };
        tmpEvents.push(event);
    });
    nowEvents.value = tmpEvents;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to get start and end of day in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636674/5089567)

```
const start = new Date();
start.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);

const end = new Date();
end.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999);
```

[Firestore query by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47005940/5089567)

```
query(
  meetingsCollection,
  where("start", ">=", start),
  where("start", "<=", end)
  orderBy("start", "asc")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. using those, I was able to deduct a solution. Could probably be a little neater, but it does the trick, and allows me to do what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
  db.collection("collection_name")
  .where("start", ">=", "02/12/2022 00:00:00.000")
  .where("start", "<=", "03/12/2022 00:00:00.000")
  .orderBy("start")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() contains the data for the document
    });
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that solution uses an old version of Firestore, I was looking to build using v9. However, thanks for the lead, it helped to deduct the solution for v9.